# Where can I find the default supported properties for YAML in Spring Boot?

Tags: spring-boot, configuration, yaml

I wish to know where can I found the list of properties supported by default.

Like:

- banner
- application

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Appendix A of the [Spring Boot Reference Guide](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/) has a listing of all properties which could be used in `application.properties`/`application.yaml`: http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html

Comment: Exactly!!! Thanks... wait 10 minutes to flag your answer as right!!!

Comment: I'd argue that your IDE is a far better choice. There is a Spring Boot integration in STS/IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate and Netbeans. All you have to do is type the key and you'll get info about it.